# Copy Constructor Error With a Template Linked List Class : no matching function for call to 'Node<int>::Node()'

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, definition, default-constructor

I'm trying to make a copy constructor for a linked list but I'm not sure how to fix this error and I've been looking for hours. The error is:

> no matching function for call to 'Node::Node()'

Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
class Node      //node is the name of class, not specific
{
public:
    T data;     //t data allows for any type of variable
    Node *next;     //pointer to a node

    Node(T Data)    //assign data value
    {
        data = Data;    //makes data = NV parameter
        next = nullptr; //makes next = to nullptr
    }
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T> * head, *tail;      //// typedef Node* head // -- head = Node* --   //// typedef Node* nodePtr =  Node* ////
public:
    LinkedList()        //constructor for Linked List
    {
        head =  nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    LinkedList(LinkedList& copy)
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        Node<T>* Curr = copy.head;


        while(Curr) //while not at end of list
               {
                   //val = copyHead->data;
                   Node<T>* newCpy = new Node<T>;
                   newCpy->data = Curr->data;
                   newCpy->next = nullptr;

                   if(head == nullptr)
                       {
                           head = tail = newCpy;
                       }
                   else
                       {
                           tail->next = newCpy;
                           tail = newCpy;
                       }

               }

    }
       ~LinkedList()
       {
           while (head)
            {
                Node<T>* tmp = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete(tmp);
            }
            head = nullptr;
       }
```

Comment: `new Node<T>` uses the default constructor for `Node<T>`, and there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class Node does not have the default constructor. It has only the following constructor

```
Node(T Data)    //assign data value
{
    data = Data;    //makes data = NV parameter
    next = nullptr; //makes next = to nullptr
}
```

And in this statement

```
Node<T>* newCpy = new Node<T>;
```

there is used the default constructor that is absent.

At least instead of these three statements

```
//val = copyHead->data;
Node<T>* newCpy = new Node<T>;
newCpy->data = Curr->data;
newCpy->next = nullptr;
```

you need to write

```
//val = copyHead->data;
Node<T>* newCpy = new Node<T>( Curr->data );
```

Pay attention to that within the while loop

```
while(Curr)
{
    //...
}
```

the pointer `Curr` is not changed. So the loop is infinite if `Curr` is not a null pointer

It seems you forgot to insert this statement

```
Curr = Curr->next;
```

before the closing brace of the loop.

Comment: I appreciate all the help, and implemented what you said, but how would the default constructor for Node look like? I'm new to constructors

Comment: @AydenCabral I showed in my answer how to use the class Node without the default constructor.

Comment: Alright, really appreciate your help!